# Create dynamic lists based on IDs and JSON responses

Tags: python, json, list

I am a beginner and I am trying to teach myself Python by using topics that are interesting to me and where I can at the same time challenge myself. I am currently struggling with a generic logical problem.

I would like to consume the CoinGecko API by using the following endpoint:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=max&interval=daily

I would like to replace "bitcoin" with a dynamic variable that refers to a list that I already have. (bitcoin, ethereum, fantom, avalanche-2)

Therefore I use the following code in combination with for i in list with a counter:

```py
counter = 0
CoinDatabase = []
for i in CoinIDList:
    if counter >2:
        break
    else:
        r = requests.get (f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/{i}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=max&interval=daily")
        data = r.json()
        prices = data["prices"]
        market_caps = data["market_caps"]
        total_volumes = data["total_volumes"]
        for i in range (len(CoinDatabase)):
            prices = data["prices"]
            CoinDatabase.append(prices)
            counter = counter+1
```

What is the smartest way to match the ID that is used in the "i" with the JSON response that I receive in every loop? Otherwise I get tons of JSONs without having the reference to what coin it belongs to.

My long term objective is to setup a small database with different values and maximum historical data for prices, market_caps, total_volumes, timestamp - just as a Python learning exercise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not store it as a dict, where the key is the coin type and the value is the json

Comment: Good idea! Thank you! How would the code look like to store it as a dic in the loop?